# Sub Directory configuration in Apache config

Tags: apache

I configured elsa on Apache web server and elsa is running on localhost/.

Now i want to add sub directory in elsa for example---localhost/mysubdir.
i created a sub directory with name mysubdir in  /usr/local/elsa/web/lib.

i want solution for how to map this sub directory in  configuration???

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /usr/local/elsa/web/lib
SetEnv ELSA_CONF /etc/elsa_web.conf


<location / >
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
    PerlSetVar psgi_app /usr/local/elsa/web/lib/Web.psgi
</location>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: Don't you want to introduce us to that "Elsa" person?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to configure subdirectories unless you have special requriements.

All documents inside the folder you configured as `DOCUMENT_ROOT` will be published by the http server without any further doing inside the configuration. Have try with your browser.

Only if you want to configure further rules like access restrictions or different options, only then you have to add a configuration section using the `<Directory>` statement. Take a look into the excellent apache http server documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is a typo but < location > should be < Location > and in my opinion it is not a better idea to allow access to all on root "/" directory. 
You might want to try the < Directory > directive

Check the < Directory > directives [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory)